# Unusual behaviour of regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

#### My Setup:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('a.html');
$arr = array();
preg_match('/<td class=\"myclass\">(.*)\<\/td>/s',$page,$arr);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

**a.html:**

```
...other content
<td class="myclass"> 
    THE 
  CONTENT 
</td>
other content...
```

---

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

---

#### If I change the line 4 of index.php to:

```
preg_match('/<td class=\"myclass\">(.*)\<\/t/s',$page,$arr);
```

#### The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <td class="myclass">
     THE 
   CONTENT
</t
    [1] => 
     THE 
   CONTENT
)
```

---

#### I can't make out what's wrong. Please help me match the content between `<td class="myclass">` and `</td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand that the 3rd paramter of `preg_match` is the matches and it will contain the match then the other elements will show the captured pattern.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

> > If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

This code
`preg_match('/<td class=\"myclass\">(.*)\<\/t/s',$page,$arr);`

When applied on

```
...other content
<td class="myclass"> 
    THE 
  CONTENT 
</td>
other content...
```

Will return the match in $arr[0] and the result of (.*) in $arr[1]. This result is correct: There is your content in [1]

```
Array
(
    [0] => <td class="myclass">
    THE
  CONTENT
</t
    [1] => 
    THE
  CONTENT
```

### Example two

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$page = 'A B C D E F';
$arr = array();
preg_match('/C (D) E/', $page, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

### Example output

```
Array
(
    [0] => C D E  // This is the string found
    [1] => D      // this is what I wanted to look for and extracted out of [0], the matched parenthesis
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to work. I edited the regex to use a different separator and get a clearer view. You may want to use the ungreedy modifier in case there is more than one myclass TD in your HTML.

I have not been able to reproduce the "array of array" behaviour you note, unless I manipulate the code to add an error -- see at bottom.

```
<?php
        $page = <<<PAGE
        ...other content
        <td class="myclass">
            THE
          CONTENT
        </td>
        other content...
PAGE;

        preg_match('#<td class="myclass">(.*)</td>#s',$page,$arr);
        print_r($arr);
?>
```

returns, as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <td class="myclass">
            THE
          CONTENT
        </td>
    [1] =>
            THE
          CONTENT

)
```

The code below is similar to yours but has been modified to cause an identical error. Doesn't seem likely you did this, though. The regexp is modified in order to **not** match, and the resulting empty array is stored into **$arr[0]** instead of `$arr`.

```
preg_match('#<td class="myclass">(.*)</ td>#s',$page,$arr[0]);
```

Returns the same error you observe:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I can duplicate the same behaviour you observe (works with `</t`, does not work with `</td>`) if I use your regexp, but modify the HTML to have `</t d>`. I still need to write to `$arr[0]` instead of `$arr` if I also want to get an identical output.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The problem persists... The problem seems to be in the last 2 chars of the regex ie. `d>` because when I remove these, all seems well (As my question implies).

Comment: Well, that could be explained by *an error in the HTML*. Are you sure the `</td>` in the HTML is not wrapped and really a `</t(carriage return)d>`? This still wouldn't explain the `Array(Array())`, but would help.

Comment: I can also confirm the original regex `/<td class=\"myclass\">(.*)\<\/t/s` works fine in my tests using the contents for a.html

Comment: yes I am sure. It is `</td>` and not `</t(carriage return)d>`.

Comment: You are using a stock `preg_match`? As per manual, `preg_match` does **not** return an *array of arrays*. You *can't* get `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )
)` from `preg_match` *even if it fails*...

Comment: so what may be the problem? Its out of my capability

Comment: @TabrezAhmed You are not understanding what is actually being returned by preg_match. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems correct. Isn't the syntax of preg_match as follows?

```
preg_match('/<td class=\"myclass\">(.*)\<\/td>/s',$page,$arr);
```

The `|` in the regex represents `or`

Comment: I had used this code before. and switched to the present code only after using this... sorry

Comment: I have replaced `|` with `/` for clear understanding. Though, syntactically it was unnecessary.